# Qgis2threejs installation problem

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.14, qgis2threejs

I have just downloaded Qgis2threejs plugin from: *Plugins/Manage and install plugins* but the tool doesn't appear in the toolbar. Does anyone know what is wrong? I'm using QGIS 2.14.1 Essen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It should be in the **Web** menu (and for me, in the toolbar highlighed by the red circle):

[image: Plugin]

*Also used QGIS 2.14.1-Essen.*